# iPhoto only sees 67 of my 388 photos

Tags: snow-leopard, ipod-touch, photos.app, ios

Preface: this is an iPod Touch 2nd Gen on iOS 4.2.1 and I am on iPhoto 11 on a MacMini from 2006 operating Snow Leopard. This iTouch was synched with an iMac I used to have which contained all of the original music, photos, contacts, etc.

I have successfully been able to grab my music off of my iTouch, I've also been able to successfully move all of my contacts, mail, etc. But one thing I seem to be having an issue with is the Photos on the device.

Photo Library says I have 388 photos. But when i connect to my mac and launch iPhoto, it says I only have 67, and all of these happen to be screenshots taken with the device.
I'm eager to erase and re-sync, but I dont want to loose the images on this device.

ps: Dropbox ALSO only detects 67 photos. 
pss: Image Capture also only shows 67 photos. All from the "Saved Images" album. No other albums.

What's going on? How can I get my Photo Library on the device safely to my Mac, I dont care if its synch from or ripped out of.

Also, it's not jailbroken.

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto and Image Capture only access photographs that are on your Camera Roll. I suspect that the 67 photos they find are the only ones on the photo roll. Other images—those in albums, etc.—cannot be downloaded by iPhoto and Image Capture.

Some third-party programs can access the non-Camera Roll photographs on your device. I haven't tried any of them, but PhoneView from Ecamm seems to be recommended frequently.

http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

I have also seen programs that attempt to extract photos from backups of the iPhone. Again, I haven't tried any of them. But they may be worth considering.